# Show Siblings via Views and taxonomy term in a block (again)

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I've got a

- D9 site
- with an Event content type and a reference to the
- place taxonomy term

In the taxonomy term, there is a field zip_code.
The taxonomy terms are setup in a hierachy:

- State 1

  - County 1
  - County 2

    - Town 1
    - Town 2
    - Town 3
- State 2

  - ...

Now, someone would search for the zip code and find e. g. Town 1.
I've got one page which will show the referenced events within town 1 - no problem at all.
[image]

Next, I'd like to show the events from Town 2 and 3 in a block.
Plenty of posts about this, yet - I can't figure it out.

In D9 it seems like, that there is no reverse relationship anymore.
I can easily add the parent, show the parent taxonomy name (County 2).
If I add a second grandparent relationship, it shows State 1 as well.
**But** I can't get the siblings / children of County 2. It seems like, there is no option to choose from in my relations:
[image]
Any idea on how to accomplish this on D9?